# API яндекс карт: С помощью какого события мы можем понять, что карту перестали двигать?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Помогите, пожалуйста, используем yandex api 3 для оформления заказов на сайте. Но не получается сделать удобный вариант определения точки, с перетаскиванием камеры - есть способ каким-нибудь событием понять, что карту перестали двигать, чтобы после завершения перетаскивания карты мы могли обратиться к координатам центральной метки и геокодировать координаты? Например, повесить прослушивание перемещения YMapCamera или типа того?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться onActionEnd в YMapListener, подробнее о нём тут https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/index#BehaviorEvents